# How to return promise's value, rather than promise itself in await/async?

Tags: node.js, promise

I have the following code. Basically reading a file then return the content.

```
var result = await promise; return result;
```

Right now it returns promise itself. Is it a way to return the result straight away?

```
FileReader.prototype.readInputFile = async function(fileName) {
  var condi = this.validateFileName(fileName);

  if(condi == true) {
    // wrap api, then wait 
    var promise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
      fs.readFile(fileName, { encoding: 'utf-8' }, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log(err);
          rej();
        }

        res(data);
      });
    });

    var result = await promise;
    return result;
  } else {
    // not valid file
  }

}
```

Comment: you can do callbacks, but they won't make any sense because promises were made to resolve the problems of callbacks. I'd suggest you keep this as a promise and use `then` to resolve it whenever you need to.

Comment: @DakshMiglani https://github.com/kenpeter/resumefront/blob/master/src/actions/jobs.js if you look at const accessToken = await getToken(config.backendAuthUrl); It seems it can get the result out of the box

Comment: yea because you're awaiting the promise, you're asking the promise to resolve. But you have wrapped it in an async function, when you make a function async, it returns a promise by default.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot. `async` function itself returns promise only. No matter what you return(or throw) in the body of function, it will eventually become a Promise.resolve() or Promise.reject().

Comment: If that is the case, in FileReader.prototype.readInputFile, is it a way to write result.then((data) => data); return data; ? @TKJohn Also have a look at this https://github.com/kenpeter/resumefront/blob/master/src/actions/jobs.js

Comment: You can `return data` in the body, or more staticly `return {}`. But the caller of `FileReader.prototype.readInputFile` could get `Promise.resolve(data)` or `Promise.resolve({})` only.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an async function the result is a promise. You can't expect an async function to return the value synchronously, right? So, the promise's value is returned properly. But the promise you see is the promise of the async function, not the one that was resolved inside it.
Put this console.log between these 2 lines and you would see it's an actual value:

```
var result = await promise;
console.log(result);
return result;
```

Answer (score -1):

Now I understand, it will return promise instead, not result. I did find a way that it is able to return result, so the code can be nicely.

FileReader.prototype.readInputFile is an async func. If any non-async func calls it, the result will be promise. If any async func call this acync func. The result is actually data.

Comment: No matter what type of func calls it, the result will only be promise. For an `async` func, it is the `await` did the trick, to retrieve actually data from promise the called returned.